# Electronics in high level of radioactivity (Fukushima example)

Tags: radioactivity, electronics

In [this website](http://www.sciencealert.com/the-robots-sent-into-fukushima-have-died) is stated that robots that were sent to Fukushima plant after the disaster were made obsolete by high levels of radioactivity.

Apart from the obvious fact, that because of nuclear decay reactions, there might be more electrons in the wiring at certain points, therefore destroying the calibrations, what are the other components that suffer from high radioactivity, and why ?

Comment: in the medium-long term, everything breaks down from being bombarded by radiation - slowly removing the outer particles, and gradually eroding it as a whole. beyond that, radiation will heat things up, so anything really heat sensitive will suffer

Comment: As you probably know, robots are being used in a possibly even more severe radiation environment: [Chernobyl Sarcophagus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernobyl_Nuclear_Power_Plant_sarcophagus)